# What's the SQL statement for returning multiple averages from a single table dynamically

Tags: mysql, logging, average, sampling

I need to generate a dynamic result based on user settings to reduce the quantity returned via post. Sample table:

```
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| cpu_name | used  | timestamp           |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| CPU 3    | 0.200 | 2015-11-19 03:09:11 |
| CPU 2    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:11 |
| CPU 1    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:11 |
| CPU 0    | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 03:09:11 |
| CPU 3    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:10 |
| CPU 2    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:10 |
| CPU 1    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:10 |
| CPU 0    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:10 |
| CPU 3    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:09 |
| CPU 2    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:09 |
| CPU 1    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:09 |
| CPU 0    | 0.122 | 2015-11-19 03:09:09 |
| CPU 3    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:07 |
| CPU 2    | 0.225 | 2015-11-19 03:09:07 |
| CPU 1    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:07 |
| CPU 0    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:07 |
| CPU 0    | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 04:45:01 |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

The rows need to be averaged, for each cpu discretely, every X hours/days/etc.

Pseudo SLQ (how do I do this with one SQL statement):

```
$time = 10
$unit = DAYS
$sample_factor = 1 //hour
for each CPU:
     $sql = "SELECT AVERAGE_every_hour(cpu_use) FROM tbl_cpu_use WHERE timestamp > (NOW() - INTERVAL ". $time. " ". $unit)"
     RETURN RESULTS BUT AS IF IT WERE ONE QUERY
```

**e.g.** 
if

> ```
> $time = 1
> $unit = Hour
> $sample_factor = 1 //hour
> ```

result would be:

```
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| cpu_name | used  | timestamp           |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| CPU 3    | 0.200 | 2015-11-19 03 |
| CPU 2    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03 |
| CPU 1    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03 |
| CPU 0    | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 03 |
| CPU 0    | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 05 |
```

but if

> ```
> $time = 1
> $unit = Hour
> $sample_factor = .5 //hour
> ```

result would be

```
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| cpu_name | used  | timestamp           |
+----------+-------+---------------------+
| CPU 3    | 0.200 | 2015-11-19 03:00 |
| CPU 2    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:00 |
| CPU 1    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:00 |
| CPU 0    | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 03:00 |
| CPU 3    | 0.200 | 2015-11-19 03:30 |
| CPU 2    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:30 |
| CPU 1    | 0.000 | 2015-11-19 03:30 |
| CPU 0    | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 03:30 |
| CPU 0    | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 05:00 |
```

Note: ignore the 'used' column values in results, assume they are averages over the time period. The 'timestamp' column and averaging is what's important.

**EDIT:** After experimenting in mySQL workbench, I think I'm getting very close with this (still difficult to determine accuracy and what to set the interval at, but I think this is getting very close and concise):

NOTE: added a hard unix timestamp when the data gets populated, very little extra processing every second and really helps with this part.

```
SET @time_interval := date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR);
SET @sample_interval := 60;

SELECT cpu_name, AVG(used) as used, @sample_interval*AVG(ROUND(unix_timestamp/@sample_interval)) as unix_timestamp FROM 
    (SELECT cpu_name, used, @sample_interval*ROUND(unix_timestamp/@sample_interval) As unix_timestamp, `timestamp` FROM BH_DB.tbl_cpu_use WHERE `timestamp`>@time_interval ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615) AS sorted_table
GROUP BY cpu_name, unix_timestamp ORDER BY unix_timestamp;
```

Comment: What if we add `| CPU 0    | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 04:45 |` to the data set?

Comment: it would depend what the sampling factor is, but in the last screen shot it would be averaged to create a line | CPU 0 | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 04:30 | OR  | CPU 0 | 0.025 | 2015-11-19 05:00 |; I don't think it really matters which one, or even if its averaged with both lines... 90 days worth of logs for 4 CPUs once a second is a lot of data to trend on a graph, so I need to get the sample size down, but accurately and averaging seems the only option. I know I can do it with many querys and a PHP loop, but I hear rumors of a ultra fast way with the processing in the SQL.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: I have now. I think you might be confusing the tables above. The actual table would never get 2015-11-19 04:45, it always gets the seconds as well. My point before is that it doesn't really matter if the 45th second gets rounded up or down when averaging many records, as long is it's consistent.

Comment: I'm certain that at least one of us is quite confused

Comment: Check below, I added a solution... not 100% certain it's doing what I want, but I think it is. Now I think I'll be able to change those two variables using PHP. If still confused, more bbackground can be found on my previous deleted post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789274/most-efficient-sql-select-queries-and-processing-algorythms-for-log-management-a

Answer (score 2):

**setup**

```
create table tbl_cpu_use
(
  cpu_name varchar(10) not null,
  used decimal(5,4) not null,
  `timestamp` timestamp not null,
  primary key ( cpu_name, `timestamp` )
);

insert into tbl_cpu_use
( cpu_name, used, `timestamp` )
values
( 'CPU 3'    , 0.200 , '2015-11-19 03:39:11' ),
( 'CPU 2'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:39:11' ),
( 'CPU 1'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:39:11' ),
( 'CPU 0'    , 0.025 , '2015-11-19 03:39:11' ),
( 'CPU 3'    , 0.200 , '2015-11-19 03:09:11' ),
( 'CPU 2'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:11' ),
( 'CPU 1'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:11' ),
( 'CPU 0'    , 0.025 , '2015-11-19 03:09:11' ),
( 'CPU 3'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:10' ),
( 'CPU 2'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:10' ),
( 'CPU 1'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:10' ),
( 'CPU 0'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:10' ),
( 'CPU 3'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:09' ),
( 'CPU 2'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:09' ),
( 'CPU 1'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:09' ),
( 'CPU 0'    , 0.122 , '2015-11-19 03:09:09' ),
( 'CPU 3'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:07' ),
( 'CPU 2'    , 0.225 , '2015-11-19 03:09:07' ),
( 'CPU 1'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:07' ),
( 'CPU 0'    , 0.000 , '2015-11-19 03:09:07' )
;

create view digits
as
select 0 as num
union all
select 1
union all
select 2
union all
select 3
union all
select 4
union all
select 5
union all
select 6
union all
select 7
union all
select 8
union all
select 9
;
```

**query**

```
-- define the sampling interval size
set @interval_seconds := 600;

select slots.cpu_name, 
-- for when cpu isnt active or no data for, use 0
avg(coalesce(cpu.used, 0)) as avg_used, 
slots.`time`
from 
(
-- construct consecutive timeslots starting from minimum timestamp
-- and definition of a decimal number as weighted sum of powers of 10
select `min` + interval (a2.num*100 + a1.num*10 + a0.num) * @interval_seconds second as `time`, cpu_names.cpu_name
from
-- get the minimum and maximum timestamp from tbl_cpu_use timeseries
(
  select max(`timestamp`) as `max`, min(`timestamp`) as `min`
  from tbl_cpu_use
) bounds
cross join
-- get all cpu_names to duplicate across timeslots when cpus arent active
(
  select distinct cpu_name
  from tbl_cpu_use
) cpu_names
cross join digits a2
cross join digits a1
cross join digits a0
-- filter timeslots between timeseries min and max
where `min` + interval (a2.num*100 + a1.num*10 + a0.num) * @interval_seconds second
<=     `max`
) slots
-- include also information for timeslots when cpus arent active
left join tbl_cpu_use cpu
on timestampdiff(second, slots.`time`, cpu.`timestamp`) between 0 and @interval_seconds
and slots.cpu_name = cpu.cpu_name
group by slots.cpu_name, slots.`time`
order by slots.`time`, slots.cpu_name
;
```

**output**

```
+----------+------------+---------------------+
| cpu_name | avg_used   | time                |
+----------+------------+---------------------+
| CPU 0    | 0.03675000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:07 |
| CPU 1    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:07 |
| CPU 2    | 0.05625000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:07 |
| CPU 3    | 0.05000000 | 2015-11-19 03:09:07 |
| CPU 0    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:19:07 |
| CPU 1    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:19:07 |
| CPU 2    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:19:07 |
| CPU 3    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:19:07 |
| CPU 0    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:29:07 |
| CPU 1    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:29:07 |
| CPU 2    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:29:07 |
| CPU 3    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:29:07 |
| CPU 0    | 0.02500000 | 2015-11-19 03:39:07 |
| CPU 1    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:39:07 |
| CPU 2    | 0.00000000 | 2015-11-19 03:39:07 |
| CPU 3    | 0.20000000 | 2015-11-19 03:39:07 |
+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ba82/1)**

Comment: Wow, that's the biggest SQL statement I've seen in years. I understand 60% of it. Will study more and attempt to implement; Before I do I just want to confirm whether you think this will be faster than implementing all this logic in PHP. Thanks again, you got SQL skills my friend.

Comment: it should be faster ( performancewise ). but may be more complex to maintain

Comment: well i;m going to upvote it for effort, even if the OP won't

Comment: Me too.. though after hours of study I still don't understand it. It helps though, gave me a direction. Please check out my edit above, I may be very very close to a 3 line solution after practicing and adding a field. The idea is to then take this query and, using PHP, assign the top variables to get the result. How efficient will this be compared to your solution?

Comment: yours will work as long as : all cpus are reported on in each interval ( what about outages, data quality, etc. ). the performance difference between these two will probably not matter unless youve got large volumes of data - benchmark and see. they are different queries though, above caters for possible data quality issues like incomplete reporting on cpus in periods etc. if you know your data quality meets above points then use the simpler query

Comment: Its close but I can't get it 100%. I've tried many variations. The inflection points of the graph I am making with this data are moving when they really shouldn't be, it's a little odd... As I press the graph it button once a second, old points are changing or I end up getting too many points; 100% certain it's not the graphing functions but the actual data; I'm so close, I don't think I even need the inner query now; I'm thinking of converting to all/only unix timestamps, one less complexity to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cpu_name, AVG(used) as used, unix_timestamp FROM 
     (SELECT cpu_name, used, (". $sql_sample_size. "*ROUND(unix_timestamp/". $sql_sample_size. ")) As unix_timestamp FROM tbl_cpu_use WHERE timestamp>(NOW() - INTERVAL ". $time. " ". $sql_unit. ")) AS sub_table 
GROUP BY cpu_name,unix_timestamp ORDER BY unix_timestamp,cpu_name DESC;
```

Appears to produce the desired output:

## cpu_name, used, unix_timestamp, unix_timestamp

```
CPU 1, 0.0420843, 1447966800.0000, 2015-11-19 16:29:59
CPU 3, 0.0248727, 1447966800.0000, 2015-11-19 16:29:59
CPU 0, 0.0728558, 1447966800.0000, 2015-11-19 16:29:59
CPU 2, 0.0388895, 1447966800.0000, 2015-11-19 16:29:59
CPU 2, 0.0405227, 1447970400.0000, 2015-11-19 17:29:59
CPU 1, 0.0445057, 1447970400.0000, 2015-11-19 17:29:59
CPU 3, 0.0288837, 1447970400.0000, 2015-11-19 17:29:59
CPU 0, 0.0663175, 1447970400.0000, 2015-11-19 17:29:59
CPU 1, 0.0522862, 1447974000.0000, 2015-11-19 18:14:48
CPU 3, 0.0358891, 1447974000.0000, 2015-11-19 18:14:48
CPU 0, 0.0551599, 1447974000.0000, 2015-11-19 18:14:48
CPU 2, 0.0378004, 1447974000.0000, 2015-11-19 18:14:48
```

Comment: Its close... the graph jumps a little.

Comment: I corrected it, the ORDER BY on the end is import, without the two in that order it was producing a fairly random ordering... now the graph doesn't jump on past values.